# Recommended paypal php sdk versions that provide for poodle sslv3 bug and actually work

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using composer to install paypal SDK's for permissions and adaptive payments. My *partial* composer.json is:

```
{
"paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php":"*",
"paypal/permissions-sdk-php":"v2.5.106",
"paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"2.*"
}
```

}

Now this works fine however if I try to use it as is it throws the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: PPBaseService::$SDK_NAME in /var/app/current/vendor/paypal/permissions-sdk-php/lib/services/Permissions/PermissionsService.php on line 22
```

this is because the PPBaseServer class does not have these variables. I found that this was a bug in a recent fix for the POODLE sslv3 issue in sdk.

I found this: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/issues/68,  which mentions that a bug was introduced with the POODLE fix so you have to override the sdk-core to sdk-core-php": "v1.4.2. My composer.json changes to:

```
{
"paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php":"*",
 "paypal/sdk-core-php": "v1.4.2",
  "paypal/permissions-sdk-php":"v2.5.106",
"paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"2.*"
}
```

this fixes the '*Access to undeclared static property*' however it reintroduces the POODLE bug.

It is possible to manually update the class files that handle the SSLv3 issue after composer runs. This works fine, but I use composer to load these files automatically on AWS.

Each time I release a build it will overwrite the changes i make, which would need to be re-made. This is a major issue in a production system.

My question is, ***what are the recommended sdk versions that handle the POODLE sslv3 issue and actually work without missing variables etc***

***EDIT***
Following Suggestion by PayPal_Martin I've modified my componer.json to the following:

```
{
"require": {
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php":"*",
    "paypal/permissions-sdk-php":"*",
    "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"*"
}
}
```

This is now throwing the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RequestEnvelope' not found in /var/app/current/paypal/Permissions.class.php on line 198

The responsible code is:

```
       $requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope(); //<<<HERE
    $requestEnvelope -> errorLanguage = self::$ERROR_LANG;
    $request = new GetPermissionsRequest();
    $request -> requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope;
    $request -> token = $token;

    try {
        $service = new PermissionsService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
        $this -> parseGetPermissionsResponse($service -> GetPermissions($request));
```

This code section is unchanged between versions and works with my previous definition.

Comment: well i came up with a non-solution that works. I've added a post deploy step in the AWS setup that overwrites the incorrect PPHttpConfig.php with the correct version. Terrible solution but...

Answer (score 0):

I would [take a look at this one instead](https://packagist.org/packages/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It's a lot easier to work with than PayPal's SDK, and much of the PayPal integration team actually prefer it themselves.

Comment: thanks i'll keep that in mind when I do my next code review. :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version for PHP5.3+ and 5.2 for the permission SDK are working fine here - https://paypal.github.io/sdk/#permissions

Installed and ran samples through composer without Poodle or missing Class issues

Keep in mind that the missing Class indicates a incorrectly installed SDK / Core SDK

5.3 - 3.8.107 - http://snag.gy/I4ba7.jpg
5.2 - 2.6.107 - http://snag.gy/gsPqW.jpg

Comment: Updated the question with the results of your suggestion. Does not work for me.

Comment: Can you confirm if this composer.json file is picking up the correct stable versions?

Comment: Interesting, with the current version provided at the #permissions url you gave PayPal_Martin the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php file is empty.

Comment: I've tried many variations, and simplified down to the basic example in the link you provided https://paypal.github.io/sdk/#permissions. I always get 'Class 'RequestEnvelope' not found' due to the autoload_classmap.php not being populated. what is wrong with this thing? I've spent about 8 hours trying to get this working without success except with older version of the code